# Argparse custom help from text file

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, argparse

I want to use the argparse library because of its flexibility, but I am having trouble disabling the default help dialogue to show a custom one from a text file. All I want to do is display the text from the text file when the "-h" or "--help" option is passed. Here is an example of how I am trying this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("file", type=str, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument("-xmin", type=float)
parser.add_argument("-xmax", type=float)
parser.add_argument("-ymin", type=float)
parser.add_argument("-ymax", type=float)
parser.add_argument("-h", "--help", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.help is True:
    print isip_get_help()
    exit(-1)
```

But it still outputs:

```
nedc_[1]: python isip_plot_det.py -h
usage: isip_plot_det.py [-xmin XMIN] [-xmax XMAX] [-ymin YMIN] [-ymax YMAX]
                        [-h]
                        file [file ...]
isip_plot_det.py: error: too few arguments
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are getting is an error message, not the help (i.e. it's not produced by your `-h`).

```
isip_plot_det.py: error: too few arguments
```

The error message shows the usage part of the normal help.  You can change that with a `usage` parameter:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(usage = 'my custom usage line')
```

You can also test the usage display with

```
parser.print_usage()
```

or

```
astr = parser.format_usage()
```

to get a printable string.

The normal `help` argument uses a special `help` action class.  Its `call` method is:

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit()
```

Notice that it displays the help with `parser.print_help()`, and then exits.  That occurs as soon as it parses the `-h` string.  That way it doesn't produce any errors like the `too few arguments` or `unrecognized arguments` (which are produced at the end of parsing).

So another way of customizing the help is to subclass `ArgumentParser`, and define your own `print_help` method.  You can also customize the `exit` and `error` methods.

The default `print_help` is:

```
def print_help(self, file=None):
    if file is None:
        file = sys.stdout
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
```

You could customize `format_help` instead.

```
 class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
     def format_help(self):
         return 'my custom help message\n   second line\n\n'
```

Sample usage:

```
In [104]: parser=MyParser(usage='custom usage')
In [105]: parser.parse_args(['-h'])
my custom help message
   second line
   ...

In [106]: parser.parse_args(['unknown'])
usage: custom usage
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: unknown
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The failure is caused by the missing required argument `file`.  The reason why `action` would not be subjected to this validation requirement is simply because they are executed first, i,e, `args.help` will be set to `True`.  However, once the parser completes parsing the arguments it would have triggered a `sys.exit` due to validation failure, and this ends with printing out the default usage and your code (that prints your desired help message) will simply never be executed (you can try calling your program as is with a `-h file` arguments and your help message should print).

You can either add your custom action using `parser.register` (not officially supported as it's considered private API, but it works - read `argparse.py` to see how it all works), or alternatively subclass `ArgumentParser` and override the `print_help` method to call `isip_get_help()`.

You could try something like this:

```
class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def print_help(self, file=None):
        print(isip_get_help())
        exit(-1)

parser = MyArgumentParser()
...
```

Leave the default `add_help` in, but with `print_help` overridden to call your custom help it should work.

Comment: You can supply the custom Action with `action=MyActionClass`, giving the class itself.  `register` is nice if you want to use a string or hide the class name, but generally isn't needed for user defined classes.  I believe the `argparse` docs has an example of a custom Action class.

Comment: Would I then use:
parser.add_argument("-h", "--help", action=MyArgumentParser)